# Does List<T> adds new objects by referencing or by creating a new instance of added object for its own use?

Tags: c#, list, class, generics

I am fairly new to c# and I am having a problem understanding a problem.

Method bellow returns only last record VALUES for all records (RecordCount times).

```cs
public List<Banke> getBanke()
{
    var listBanke = new List<Banke>();

    using (SqlConnection NConnection = new SqlConnection(Params.ConnectionStr))
    {
        NConnection.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BANKE]", NConnection))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            var recBanke = new Banke();  // <- notice this line !!!

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    recBanke.banka_id = reader["BANKA_ID"] as int? ?? 0;
                    recBanke.pun_naziv = reader["PUN_NAZIV"] as string;
                    recBanke.sk_naziv = reader["SK_NAZIV"] as string;
                    recBanke.ino = reader["ino"] as bool? ?? false;

                    listBanke.Add(recBanke);                              
                }                                              
            }

            reader.Close();                    
        }
    }
    return listBanke;
}
```

Now, if I change it to this :

```
public List<Banke> getBanke()
{
    var listBanke = new List<Banke>();

    using (SqlConnection NConnection = new SqlConnection(Params.ConnectionStr))
    {
        NConnection.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BANKE]", NConnection))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    var recBanke = new Banke(); // <- notice this line !!!

                    recBanke.banka_id = reader["BANKA_ID"] as int? ?? 0;
                    recBanke.pun_naziv = reader["PUN_NAZIV"] as string;
                    recBanke.sk_naziv = reader["SK_NAZIV"] as string;
                    recBanke.ino = reader["ino"] as bool? ?? false;

                    listBanke.Add(recBanke);                              
                }                                              
            }

            reader.Close(); 
        }
    }
    return listBanke;
}
```

everything is OK. It returns all records properly.

Can someone please explain this to me ? I mean why does the first case returns only last record values RecordCount times and second case works well ?

Comment: In the first code block you are simply changing the properties of a single `Banke` instance. In the second you are creating a new instance for each row returned from the DB.

Comment: Learn, how reference types in C# work.

Comment: Closed as too broad instead of duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156363/listt-add-creates-duplicates-c-sharp by mistake... Consider duplicate.

Comment: "Need someone to explain this to me" is a damned stupid title for a question. Please change this to contain more details...

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24219660/1069757

Comment: I do realize this but I realy don't have a title for this question. As I already said I am having problem understanding problem ?

Comment: You could have looked at duplicate I suggested and rename your question similarly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you are overwriting the same instance of the Banke variable.

You need a new instance of each object. you could do what you are doing like this to avoid confusion.

```
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BANKE]", NConnection))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // you don't need to test if your reader has rows

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listBanke.Add(new Banke{
                   banka_id = reader["BANKA_ID"] as int? ?? 0,
                   pun_naziv = reader["PUN_NAZIV"] as string,
                   sk_naziv = reader["SK_NAZIV"] as string,
                   ino = reader["ino"] as bool? ?? false
                });                              
            }                                              
        reader.Close(); 
    }
```

Comment: I understand that, but why does the first case returns VALUES OF LAST RECORD in table FOR RECORDCOUNT times ?

Comment: @EmirZ because you are putting the same copy of recBank in the list over and over again. So when you change it you are modifiyng all the elements in the list.

Comment: So the SqlDataReader (reader) does not overwrite values in "recBanke" while it iterates thru records ?

Comment: @EmirZ No, it does overwrite, thats the problem. all the "slots" in `listBanke` **all point to a single Banke object**, so when you overwrite `banka_id` all the slots update (Because only one object exists), in your 2nd example you create a new `recBanke` each loop so you are not overwriting the old values.

Comment: Thanks Scott! Now I understand it.